# Calculating the operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis

In the following question, I am asked to calculate the operator norm. I don't quite get what the operator exactly does, though. The question is:

Show that the linear map A, which assigns to every $x \in C[0,a]$ the function $s\mapsto s\int_0^a x(t)dt$ in $C[0,a]$, has the operator norm $a^2$.

I know that the definition of the operator norm is $\Vert T\Vert = \inf\{C\ge 0:\Vert Tx\Vert \le C\Vert x \Vert\quad \forall x\in X\}=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\Vert Tx \Vert}{\Vert x\Vert}=\sup_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\Vert Tx\Vert=\sup_{\Vert x\Vert\le 1}\Vert Tx\Vert.$

But I am not quite sure how to apply that definition, as in the question there are two functions $s$ and $x$. Should I show that $\sup_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\Vert s\int_0^a x(t)dt\Vert=a^2$ or $\sup_{\Vert s\Vert=1}\Vert s\int_0^a x(t)dt\Vert=a^2$? And how should I proceed after that?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $Tx$ is a continuous function on $[0,a]$ (with variable $s$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
|Tx(s)|&=|s|\left|\int_{0}^{a}x(t)dt\right|\leq|s|\int_{0}^{a}\|x\|_{\infty}dt\leq|a|\|x\|_{\infty}|a|=|a|^{2}\|x\|_{\infty},
\end{align*}
so $\|Tx\|_{\infty}\leq|a|^{2}\|x\|_{\infty}$, hence $\|T\|\leq|a|^{2}$. Now put $x=\dfrac{a}{|a|}$, then $T(a/|a|)(s)=s\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a}\dfrac{a}{|a|}dt=s|a|$, and $\|T(a/|a|)\|_{\infty}=|a|^{2}$, so $\|T\|=|a|^{2}$.